# The type or namespace name 'Products' does not exist in the namespace 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels'

Tags: umbraco

I am maintaining an Umbraco solution (version 7.15.3).
Recently a bug has been discovered: Upon navigating to a certain page it fails with the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Products' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

This isn't really surprising, there have been several version upgrades recently, performed by people who are no longer with the company. For instance, the ModelBuilder (which I believe is related to this) was recently upgraded from version 3.0.7 to 3.0.10.

Not knowing much about the issue, I first trried to hunt down the Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels. To my surprise it wasn't in umbraco\Umbraco.Web\Lib or umbraco\Umbraco.Web\bin and when I built the solution it wasn't generated.

I eventually found it in a folder that looked like this:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\74e32662\fd1a65f5\assembly\dl3\09bc313a\c9c37261_f6d1d501

Strange thing is, while the UAT server has one such location, the production server has 4 (the paths only differ in the last folder name).

Luckily, while this error shows up in production, and when I run the project locally, the page just works on the UAT environment. So I took the dll from UAT and copied to umbraco\UmbracoWeb\bin on the production server. This fixed the issue, but it's just a temporary solution. Unless I fix it properly, the next time someone makes a change and redeploys production, the problem will likely come back.

I have a page called Products.cshtml which has the following on the first two lines:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Products>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
```

The 'Products' bit at the first line is underlined and it gives me the same error in VS as the one I get at runtime. Suspecting the upgrade of the ModelBuilder assembly might have been the cause, I tried checking out a version from before the upgrade. But the error is still there.

The solution also has another project that is referenced from the Umbraco project. It has a class called Products, but I don't know if this is in any way related. The Products class doesn't inherit anything.

How can I fix this? Is there a way to recreate the correct Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels dll and have it referenced properly?

Answer (score 0):

ModelsBuilder is driven by a few settings that are held in your web.config, and can be configured to behave in a number of different ways -  see here for reference - [Models Builder Documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/templating/modelsbuilder/configuration)

It sounds like you've got this set to `PureLive`

My preference has always been to include these as part of my source code, by generating them when something changes and having them as part of my solution

[image]

Whenever you make a change to a Document Type via Umbraco Admin, these files will get regenerated and can be checked in as part of your source control. They can then be compiled into a dll / project of your choice.

[image]

Hope this helps